# Blazor: New page is not rendered in MainLayout @body

Tags: blazor

I have created a new Blazor Server project in VS 2019 (core 3). It builds and runs just fine.

I have added another page (with a model) and put some content into it.

I then add a link to it from the menu and... It kind of works.

The page is shown but not inside the @body of the MainLayout view. It is just renderen the page itself.

Any idea what might be going on? I haven't added the code here because its just out-of-box stuff.

Thanks in advance and have an awesome day

Comment: can you show us the code and the name and extension of the new file. and the code you are using to address the new page.

Comment: Is the layout you are expecting to be rendered the same one you are referencing in the DefaultLayout attribute on your RouteView tag in the Router of your App.razor?

Answer (score 1):

OK, just ran into this. Stupid, subtle mistake: I added my page as "Razor Page" instead of a Razor Component thinking that I was adding a Blazor "page", not a component. Changing the extension from .cshtml to .razor resolved it. Doh!

Comment: Old habits die hard, sometimes.  I'm sure you're not the first or last! :D